# GWT and Hibernate - NoClassDefFoundError when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, gwt, jakarta-ee

In my GWT service on server side I use Hibernate. When creating a SessionFactory I get following error:

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.Socket is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details."

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be that you are trying to use Hibernate on Google App Engine, but [Hibernate is incompatible with Google App Engine](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine)

Comment: Ok. This looks unattractive. But what if I deploy my GWT app on Tomcat? Will it then run with Hibernate? As I understand, the issues with GWT and Hibernate is only when you deploy your GWT app on GAE? I'm I right?

Comment: The link is broken, please update if possible. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a common GWT issue in debug mode - eg if you're looking to get postgres data locally before a prod install, you can't using the app engine.  But when tomcat (or whatever) is serving the servlets, all is normal.